# Meaningful State Representations with Autoencoders & Embedding Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As I understand, Embedding Layers are simply lookup matrices, weights of which are learned by the optimisation problem.

Suppose, for this example, my dataset contains a single categorical variable. For example, I would like to auto encode a sentence of words to itself, to learn the sentence representation.

```
# example model
input = tf.keras.layers.Input()
embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(99)(input)
encoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM()(embed)
decoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM()(encoder)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input, decoder)
```

The error will minimise the difference between `embed` and `decoder` outputs.

However, since embeddings are learned depending on optimisation condition, I think that I will end up learning trivial representations e.g.

the embedding matrix is all ones, and decoder always outputs ones. (Or zeros even), giving me a 100% accuracy in training.

For example, in the embedding matrix all words are just a vector of ones, and the auto encoder simply returns ones.

What I would like to do is to learn a meaningful representation of categorical variables.